# Excel crashes on Direct Input - Excel (VBA)

Tags: excel, crash, vba

I have a strange bug problem where excel keeps crashing when I simply input a value in a **Table cell** not range.

More Illustration on the problem:

I made a workbook (Shorthand: WB) full of codes using (MS Excel 2010), the WB have more than 15 sheets and lots of *tables* and *defined names*; each sheet has at least 1 table.Everything works fine, now, when I tried the WB on (MS Excel 2016) **some** sheets causes the application to crash when I input values (e.g. 10,20,A,B, ... , etc) in **table cells**, not a normal range, but when I input my value as formula (e.g. =10) everything is fine, also I have tried entering the values in an empty range then copying them to the table cells and this works fine.

At first I suspected that it has something to do with the missing reference as I was using OWC11 in the PC with (MS Excel 2010) and it was not there on the PC with (MS Excel 2016) so I installed but the problem is still there.

Also, for info I tried the WB on multiple PCs with (MS Excel 2013 & 2016)

I really can't find any logical reason for this crash.

[image: Table vs Range]

---

**EDIT:**

I tried adding data validation to the cell causing the crash then remove it and I was surprised that the crash was gone !!!

Comment: To know the difference take a look at these: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2011/09/23/excel-tables-ranges/

Comment: cool. What kind of error is it? If it is a VBA error, then the code would be useful.

Comment: No, its not a VBA error at all its a Windows Error "The Program has stopped working" and excel is terminated after. Its the error that you get when an application crashes.

Comment: cool. Do you have some events in those worksheets?

Comment: I have many events but I am not sure if this the case as there are other sheets are working normally.